# Why does SwiftUI require _propertyName style initialization for @Binding and @State vars?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

If you try to create a SwiftUI `View` that has an @State or @Binding property

ex:

```
struct TestView: View {
    @Binding var foo: String

    init(foo: Binding<String>) {
        self.foo = foo
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text(foo)
    }
}
```

you will get the error: `Cannot assign value of type 'Binding<String>' to type 'String'`

If you change the initializer to read:

```
init(foo: Binding<String>) {
    _foo = foo
}
```

It 'just works'.

What is going on with the ' _ ' syntax? What is this actually doing? It looks like you're setting an ivar in ObjC but I highly doubt this is what is happening.

Comment: You can also write self._foo = foo;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Binding` just creates another property for you, as like

```
struct TestView: View {
    @Binding var foo: String
```

is equal to

```
struct TestView: View {
    var foo: String
    var _foo: Binding<String>
```

so now it is clear that in the following init you just initialize corresponding member

```
init(foo: Binding<String>) {
    _foo = foo
}
```

Comment: Is this documented anywhere? I was trying to look at the source for Binding but didn't see anything about creating the shadow variable...

Comment: @JoeSusnick, this is generic property wrappers syntax concept, see [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0258-property-wrappers.md#initialization-of-synthesized-storage-properties)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the documentation! Makes a lot more sense now!